# Assertion failure error when swiping to delete cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

Breakpoint is at the [self.tableView...] line.

This is the first time I've come across such an error. I'm messing with a cocoapod that implements swipe to delete functionality.

```
- (void)swipeTableViewCell:(MCSwipeTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerState:(MCSwipeTableViewCellState)state withMode:(MCSwipeTableViewCellMode)mode
{
    NSLog(@"IndexPath : %@ - MCSwipeTableViewCellState : %d - MCSwipeTableViewCellMode : %d", [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell], state, mode);

    if (mode == MCSwipeTableViewCellModeExit)
    {

        // Remove the item in your data array and then remove it with the following method
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


    }
}
```

Also, assuming there is a way to fix this, would it be possible to delete the object from my Parse backend? Originally I was using:

```
PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [self loadObjects];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assertion failure can only be caused by an explicit call to one of the `NSAssert` functions. These are used to test that certain assumptions made by a developer are true. They "assert" the truth of these assumptions, and throw an exception if they're ever not true.

As far as I know, no assertions ship in any of the Apple developer libraries. That means either you have put an assertion into your code, or — more likely — there's one in the code of the cocoapod you're using. Get the source and do a global search for "NSAssert" to get a sense of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when deleting items from a tableView you need to modify the underlying data first.  In other words if you draw your table from an array, first remove the row from the array, then delete the row from the table.

If that does not work, you can try:

```
[mytableView beginUpdates];

//do my changes

[mytableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Hm. Still throwing the same assertion but now to [self.tableView endUpdates];